# Size of Data Moving between GNURadio Blocks

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am trying to build a basic GNURadio example where I have a text file that contains some text and I want to add to it a preamble to be able to detect the beginning of the data at the receiver. Next I want to modulate it with GMSK and transmit it (with a USRP). At the receiver another USRP will take samples of the received signal and pass it to the GMSK Demod block then a correlator will search for the preamble, remove it, and pass the data of the text to a File sink where it will be stored in a text file.

```
--------------    ----------------    ----------    ------
-Source File - -> -Packet Encoder- -> -GMSK Mod- -> -USRP-
--------------    ----------------    ----------    ------



------    ------    ------------    ----------------    -----------
-USRP- -> -Sync- -> -GMSK Demod- -> -Packet Decoder- -> -File Sink-
------    ------    ------------    ----------------    -----------
```

Assuming phase and frequency shifts are corrected, my understanding of how this will work is that GNURadio will take a chunk of the data in the text file and pass it to the next block where a preamble will be added, then the GMSK will modulate this sequence and send it to the USRP (and this will be repeated until all the text in the text file is read). My concern is at the receiver, how will the receive blocks know the size (length) of the data the scheduler is passing on every 'loop' (i.e., the number of bytes from the text file + length of the preamble)? Because if the scheduler at the receiver passes fewer symbols to a block than the length of the text chunk + preamble, then I might be able to detect the preamble but then I will only have part of the text that was sent (along with that preamble and that specific sequence), and the remaining bytes of the text will be passed by the scheduler in the next 'loop' which will consequently be removed (lost) because of preamble search.

Unfortunately I could not find a documentation on this, so I might be missing something. My main question is: How can I make the scheduler take sufficient amount of symbols in order to be able to find the preamble and extract the accompanying text bytes, but at the same time allow the blocks to repeat the same steps for the next sequence of text + preamble?

Comment: So, you are trying to implement your own synchronizer or you use an existing one?

Comment: I am using the Polyphase and costas loop blocks for sync.

Comment: I think my question is: if I am creating packets 1000 symbols long, how will I be able at the receiver to process only 1000 symbols (or a multiple of 1000 symbols) at a time, regardless of what the scheduler passes between blocks? If the scheduler passes less that 1000 symbols to a block (500 for example), how will I be able to access the more symbols and process a whole packet of 1000 symbols and then let the scheduler know that I processed 1000 symbols not 500?

Comment: So you're basically trying to avoid buffering your data?